# Picking out specific information out a text file with Scanner

Tags: java, regex

I am having trouble finding an efficient way to pick out specific data from a text file in this format, with numerous lines.

```
<"Name" "double" "double" "double" [...]>
```

The amount of doubles varies on every line of the txt file,
I am only interested to pick out the first double of every line in the txt file.

The way I am trying to do it is with:

```
Scanner doubleScan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("(\\w)(\\s+)");
String[] columnOne = elementScan.next().split(" ");
```

Trying to make the scanner expect with regex but does not really work if unknown amount of doubles in a line. Then trying to store all the picked out (1st of every line) doubles in an array

Would appreciate any suggestions, with Scanner only.

Comment: Use the Scanner if you want to parse the file, use the BufferedReader if you want to read the file line by line.

Comment: Does it really have to be done with Scanner? In your code example you are using `split` so it isn't pure Scanner solution anyway.

Comment: If you can use `split` then maybe use `nextLine()` instead of `next()` to get entire line, then split it on space and read element `[1]` of result array. BTW you will have to do it in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scanner.nextLine()` to read line by line and then use plit method and take second element from the array. Alternatively if you are so partcular about using only scanners you can create another scanner for each line and check for double using `nextDouble()` method. Example.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
            while (fileScanner.hasNext()) {
                Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(fileScanner.nextLine());
                while (lineScanner.hasNext()) {
                    if (lineScanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                        System.out.println("First Double :" + lineScanner.nextDouble());
                        break;
                    } else {
                        lineScanner.next();
                    }
                }
                lineScanner.close();
            }
            fileScanner.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Helpful answer that must have taken quite some time to compose, +1 :)